# On Scrolling Navbar Go Behind Slider And Silder Parallax Effect Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

when i scrolling down my menubar go behind the cycle slider i tried `z-index` 1 but its not working please give any soloution i dont know what going wrong

```
    </div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="section_about">

</div>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section_about{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: demo https://fiddle.jshell.net/gopjdo7d/

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a

```
 display: block;
```

or

```
 display: table;
```

on both of them. Set the index 2 for the menu, and 0 for the slide container. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#slider-main #slider img{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position:absolute !important;
      z-index:2!important;
}
```

Comment: it fixed but it make my slider about 40px in height